# Django - How to override filter on a model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I'm curious if there's a best practice, or recommended way to accomplish this?

Say I have a model like this:

```
class Cat(models.Model):
    field1=models.CharField(...)
    field2=models.CharField(...)
    evil=models.BooleanField(...)
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is I want no views to ever be able to access Cat records where evil is True.

Do I really need to add .filter(evil=False) to every Cat.objects.filter call, or is there some way to do it once in the class and make the evil cats never show up anywhere?

Comment: I think a custom manager is the way to go here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers

Comment: I agree @Jingo. Make it an answer and you have my vote.

Comment: Thanks Jingo.  That does look promising.  If it works out I'll write up my own answer here.  I'd still be curious if anyone else has different ideas but I'll give this a shot.

Comment: @Greg: with a custom manager, keep in mind that the first manager becomes the "default" and should be unfiltered as a result, so you should define `objects = models.Manager()` and then `seenoevil = NoEvilCatsManager()`

Comment: @ChrisPratt, but I want the default manager to not allow evil cats.  So I'm thinking objects = NoEvilCatsManager() <is> what I want, right?

Comment: right, but you wont see evil=True objects in the admin then, except you define a new queryset for the admin view.

Comment: @Jingo, They're so evil they shouldn't even appear in the admin :-)  But good point about that.

Comment: Never, ever, ever filter the default manager. It's not just used in the admin, but in many places across the Django infrastructure. It's just not a good idea; you *will* break things; just don't do it.

Comment: @chris, as far as I understand this only applies to so called "automatic managers". There should be no problem with a custom default manager, except that there are results excluded and you will not be able to access these.

Comment: The default manager, automatic manager, whatever you call it, it's all the same. The first manager listed on the model (or the "automatic" one Django adds if you don't declare *any* managers on your model), becomes the default, and should *not* be filtered in any way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, a custom manager could fit in here. Just have a look into the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers). And like Chris Pratt said, keep in mind that the first manager becomes the default one.

Hope this leads into the right direction.

Update (maybe you could do it like this):

```
from django.db import models

class EvilCategoryManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        return super(EvilCategoryManager, self).get_query_set().filter(evil=False)

class Cat(models.Model):
    #.... atrributes here
    objects = models.Manager()
    no_evil_cats = EvilCategoryManager()
```

Comment: Thanks, do you mean return super(EvilCategoryManager...?

Comment: Why don't you just return `super(EvilCategoryManager, self).filter(evil=False)`?

Comment: From docs: If you inherit from models.Manager you should override its get_query_function in order to override its base query set, but I think you could also do return Cat.objects.filter(evil=False)...

Comment: Note, that while you should make the unfiltered manager the default (first) one, it does not need to be named "objects". So you can have `class Cat(models.Model): all_objects = models.Manager(); objects = EvilCategoryManager()`

Comment: you need to override ```get_queryset``` instead of ```get_query_set```

Comment: This may be the best way to solve the OP's problem, but it is not an answer to the question in the title.