# Maintaining history by soft deleting the row of table

Tags: python, mysql, django

Initially, I was hard deleting SQL rows. Now, I want to soft delete the row by adding a new column in table '***is_active***'. if is_active=False, this means the row is deleted, and it is now part of history.

But the concern is with the other tables where this table is referenced via a foreign key. earlier, when deleting this row, automatically deletes the record from other tables(model.cascade). Example;

```
Table 1{
id uuid,
is_active bool,
.
.
}

Table2{
id uuid,
fk foreignKey(Table1, on_delete=models.cascade)
}

Table3{
id uuid,
fk foreignKey(Table1, on_delete=models.cascade)
}
```

Now, if I will soft delete the table1(making is_active=False), then I have the following option,

1. Add ***is_active*** columns to all other tables also which is referencing table1. and follow the same procedure to these tables as for table1.

**ISSUE**: it will be a very hectic task, as some other tables might be pointing to table2, which in result may be referenced by some other tables. and we have manually set is_active=False for table2 and table3.

QS. Is there any better approach for soft_deleting the table? like something like that,

```
Table2{
id uuid,
fk foreignKey(Table1, on_is_active_is_False=set.is_active=False),
is_active bool
}
```

Comment: You could design a model Manager for `Table2` and `Table3` to automatically filter out relationships which `Table1` record are not active? This means whenever you use `objects.all()` or `objects.filter()` it will apply default filter`(table1__active=True)`. See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11617918/11475846

Comment: Yeah that will solve the problem partially. now, I want that when table1__active is set to false, i.e one row entry is deleted, then table2__active and table3__active should also be set to false.

Comment: Ah my answer was more for if you didn't want to have `active` fields on both `Table2` and `Table3`. In the case you have given I'll write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write a **signal** to change the state of foreign key relationships after the `is_active` field has been altered on `Table1`.

**models.py**

```py
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

def set_active(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.table2_set.all().update(is_active=instance.is_active)
    instance.table3_set.all().update(is_active=instance.is_active)

post_save.connect(set_active, sender=table1)
```

Using the `post_save` signal it will update all the relationships whenever the `is_active` status changes. `Table2` and `Table3` should now reflect the value of `Table1` whenever in changes.

Comment: how u are handling the case, that this signal will only be called when the is_active flag of sender is set to false?

Comment: @Ayush The code will change the active status of other models whenever the `Table1` model is changed. This will reflect if it is either False or True.